# Could not get transform from odom to base_link

Tags: navigation, odometry, kinect, ros-kinetic, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running rtabmap with an rgb-d sensor and get the following error:

```
We received odometry message, but we cannot get the corresponding TF odom->base_link at data stamp 1533265358.770186s (odom msg stamp is 1533265358.757750s). Make sure TF of odometry is also published to get more accurate pose estimation. This warning is only printed once.
```

This is my launch file

```
<launch>
  <!-- Convenience launch file to launch odometry, rtabmap and rtabmapviz nodes at once -->

  <!-- For stereo:=false
        Your RGB-D sensor should be already started with "depth_registration:=true".
        Examples:
           $ roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch depth_registration:=true 
           $ roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch depth_registration:=true -->
           
  <!-- For stereo:=true
        Your camera should be calibrated and publishing rectified left and right 
        images + corresponding camera_info msgs. You can use stereo_image_proc for image rectification.
        Example:
           $ roslaunch rtabmap_ros bumblebee.launch -->
     
  <!-- Choose between RGB-D and stereo -->      
  <arg name="stereo"          default="false"/>
 
  <!-- Choose visualization -->
  <arg name="rtabmapviz"              default="true" /> 
  <arg name="rviz"                    default="false" />
  
  <!-- Localization-only mode -->
  <arg name="localization"            default="false"/>
  
  <!-- sim time for convenience, if playing a rosbag -->
  <arg name="use_sim_time"            default="false"/>
  <param if="$(arg use_sim_time)" name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
  
  <!-- Corresponding config files -->
  <arg name="cfg"                     default="" /> <!-- To change RTAB-Map's parameters, set the path of config file (*.ini) generated by the standalone app -->
  <arg name="gui_cfg"                 default="~/.ros/rtabmap_gui.ini" />
  <arg name="rviz_cfg"                default="$(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/config/rgbd.rviz" />
  
  <arg name="frame_id"                default="base_link"/>     <!-- Fixed frame id, you may set "base_link" or "base_footprint" if they are published -->
  <arg name="odom_frame_id"           default=""/>                <!-- If set, TF is used to get odometry instead of the topic -->
  <arg name="map_frame_id"            default="map"/>
  <arg name="ground_truth_frame_id"   default=""/>     <!-- e.g., "world" -->
  <arg name="ground_truth_base_frame_id" default=""/>  <!-- e.g., "tracker", a fake frame matching the frame "frame_id" (but on different TF tree) -->
  <arg name="namespace"               default="rtabmap"/>
  <arg name="database_path"           default="~/.ros/rtabmap.db"/>
  <arg name="queue_size"              default="10"/>
  <arg name="wait_for_transform"      default="0.2"/>
  <arg name="args"                    default=""/>              <!-- delete_db_on_start, udebug -->
  <arg name="rtabmap_args"            default="$(arg args)"/>   <!-- deprecated, use "args" argument -->
  <arg name="launch_prefix"           default=""/>              <!-- for debugging purpose, it fills launch-prefix tag of the nodes -->
  <arg name="output"                  default="screen"/>        <!-- Control node output (screen or log) -->

  <!-- if timestamps of the input topics are synchronized using approximate or exact time policy-->
  <arg     if="$(arg stereo)" name="approx_sync"  default="true"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg stereo)" name="approx_sync"  default="true"/>         
   
  <!-- RGB-D related topics -->
  <arg name="rgb_topic"               default="/camera/rgb/image_rect_color" />
  <arg name="depth_topic"             default="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw" />
  <arg name="camera_info_topic"       default="/camera/rgb/camera_info" />
  <arg name="depth_camera_info_topic" default="$(arg camera_info_topic)" />
  
  <!-- stereo related topics -->
  <arg name="stereo_namespace"        default="/camera"/>
  <arg name="left_image_topic"        default="$(arg stereo_namespace)/left/image_rect_color" />
  <arg name="right_image_topic"       default="$(arg stereo_namespace)/right/image_rect" />      <!-- using grayscale image for efficiency -->
  <arg name="left_camera_info_topic"  default="$(arg stereo_namespace)/left/camera_info" />
  <arg name="right_camera_info_topic" default="$(arg stereo_namespace)/right/camera_info" />
  
  <!-- Already synchronized RGB-D related topic, with rtabmap_ros/rgbd_sync nodelet -->
  <arg name="rgbd_sync"               default="false"/>         <!-- pre-sync rgb_topic, depth_topic, camera_info_topic -->
  <arg name="approx_rgbd_sync"        default="true"/>          <!-- false=exact synchronization -->
  <arg name="subscribe_rgbd"          default="$(arg rgbd_sync)"/>
  <arg name="rgbd_topic"              default="rgbd_image" />
  <arg name="depth_scale"             default="1.0" />
  
  <arg name="compressed"              default="false"/>         <!-- If you want to subscribe to compressed image topics -->
  <arg name="rgb_image_transport"     default="compressed"/>    <!-- Common types: compressed, theora (see "rosrun image_transport list_transports") -->
  <arg name="depth_image_transport"   default="compressedDepth"/>  <!-- Depth compatible types: compressedDepth (see "rosrun image_transport list_transports") -->
   
  <arg name="subscribe_scan"          default="false"/>
  <arg name="scan_topic"              default="/scan"/>
  <arg name="subscribe_scan_cloud"    default="false"/>
  <arg name="scan_cloud_topic"        default="/scan_cloud"/>
  <arg name="scan_normal_k"           default="0"/>
   
  <arg name="visual_odometry"          default="true"/>          <!-- Launch rtabmap visual odometry node -->
  <arg name="icp_odometry"             default="false"/>         <!-- Launch rtabmap icp odometry node -->
  <arg name="odom_topic"               default="/odometry/filtered"/>          <!-- Odometry topic name -->
  <arg name="vo_frame_id"              default="$(arg odom_topic)"/> <!-- Visual/Icp odometry frame ID for TF -->
  <arg name="odom_tf_angular_variance" default="1"/>             <!-- If TF is used to get odometry, this is the default angular variance -->
  <arg name="odom_tf_linear_variance"  default="1"/>             <!-- If TF is used to get odometry, this is the default linear variance -->
  <arg name="odom_args"                default=""/>              <!-- More arguments for odometry (overwrite same parameters in rtabmap_args) -->
  <arg name="odom_sensor_sync"         default="false"/>
  <arg name="odom_guess_frame_id"        default=""/>
  <arg name="odom_guess_min_translation" default="0"/>
  <arg name="odom_guess_min_rotation"    default="0"/> 
  <arg name="imu_topic"                default="/imu/data"/>          <!-- only used with VIO approaches -->
  
  <arg name="subscribe_user_data"      default="false"/>             <!-- user data synchronized subscription -->
  <arg name="user_data_topic"          default="/user_data"/>
  <arg name="user_data_async_topic"    default="/user_data_async" /> <!-- user data async subscription (rate should be lower than map update rate) -->
  
  <!-- These arguments should not be modified directly, see referred topics without "_relay" suffix above -->
  <arg if="$(arg compressed)"     name="rgb_topic_relay"           default="$(arg rgb_topic)_relay"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg compressed)" name="rgb_topic_relay"           default="$(arg rgb_topic)"/>
  <arg if="$(arg compressed)"     name="depth_topic_relay"         default="$(arg depth_topic)_relay"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg compressed)" name="depth_topic_relay"         default="$(arg depth_topic)"/>
  <arg if="$(arg compressed)"     name="left_image_topic_relay"    default="$(arg left_image_topic)_relay"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg compressed)" name="left_image_topic_relay"    default="$(arg left_image_topic)"/>
  <arg if="$(arg compressed)"     name="right_image_topic_relay"   default="$(arg right_image_topic)_relay"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg compressed)" name="right_image_topic_relay"   default="$(arg right_image_topic)"/>

  <!-- Nodes -->
  <group ns="$(arg namespace)">
     
    <!-- relays -->
    <group unless="$(arg stereo)">
      <group unless="$(arg subscribe_rgbd)">
        <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_rgb" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="$(arg rgb_image_transport) in:=$(arg rgb_topic) raw out:=$(arg rgb_topic_relay)" />
        <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_depth" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="$(arg depth_image_transport) in:=$(arg depth_topic) raw out:=$(arg depth_topic_relay)" />
      </group>
      <group if="$(arg rgbd_sync)">
        <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_rgb" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="$(arg rgb_image_transport) in:=$(arg rgb_topic) raw out:=$(arg rgb_topic_relay)" />
        <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_depth" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="$(arg depth_image_transport) in:=$(arg depth_topic) raw out:=$(arg depth_topic_relay)" />
        <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="rgbd_sync" args="standalone rtabmap_ros/rgbd_sync" output="$(arg output)">
          <remap from="rgb/image"       to="$(arg rgb_topic_relay)"/>
          <remap from="depth/image"     to="$(arg depth_topic_relay)"/>
          <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg camera_info_topic)"/>
          <remap from="rgbd_image"      to="$(arg rgbd_topic)"/>
          <param name="approx_sync"     type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_rgbd_sync)"/>
          <param name="queue_size"      type="int"    value="$(arg queue_size)"/>
          <param name="depth_scale"     type="double" value="$(arg depth_scale)"/>
        </node>
      </group>
    </group>
    <group if="$(arg stereo)">
      <group unless="$(arg subscribe_rgbd)">
        <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_left"  type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="$(arg rgb_image_transport) in:=$(arg left_image_topic) raw out:=$(arg left_image_topic_relay)" />
        <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_right" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="$(arg rgb_image_transport) in:=$(arg right_image_topic) raw out:=$(arg right_image_topic_relay)" />
      </group>
      <group if="$(arg rgbd_sync)">
        <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_left"  type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="$(arg rgb_image_transport) in:=$(arg left_image_topic) raw out:=$(arg left_image_topic_relay)" />
        <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_right" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="$(arg rgb_image_transport) in:=$(arg right_image_topic) raw out:=$(arg right_image_topic_relay)" />
        <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="rgbd_sync" args="standalone rtabmap_ros/stereo_sync" output="$(arg output)">
          <remap from="left/image_rect"   to="$(arg left_image_topic_relay)"/>
          <remap from="right/image_rect"  to="$(arg right_image_topic_relay)"/>
          <remap from="left/camera_info"  to="$(arg left_camera_info_topic)"/>
          <remap from="right/camera_info" to="$(arg right_camera_info_topic)"/>
          <remap from="rgbd_image"      to="$(arg rgbd_topic)"/>
          <param name="approx_sync"     type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_rgbd_sync)"/>
          <param name="queue_size"      type="int"    value="$(arg queue_size)"/>
        </node>
      </group>
    </group>
    
    <group unless="$(arg rgbd_sync)">
       <node if="$(arg subscribe_rgbd)" name="republish_rgbd_image"  type="relay" pkg="topic_tools" args="$(arg rgbd_topic) $(arg rgbd_topic)_relay" />
    </group>

    <!-- Visual odometry -->
    <group unless="$(arg icp_odometry)">
      <group if="$(arg visual_odometry)">
      
        <!-- RGB-D Odometry -->
        <node unless="$(arg stereo)" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odometry" output="$(arg output)" args="$(arg rtabmap_args) $(arg odom_args)" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
          <remap from="rgb/image"       to="$(arg rgb_topic_relay)"/>
          <remap from="depth/image"     to="$(arg depth_topic_relay)"/>
          <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg camera_info_topic)"/>
          <remap     if="$(arg rgbd_sync)" from="rgbd_image" to="$(arg rgbd_topic)"/>
          <remap unless="$(arg rgbd_sync)" from="rgbd_image" to="$(arg rgbd_topic)_relay"/>
          <remap from="odom"            to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
      
          <param name="frame_id"                    type="string" value="$(arg frame_id)"/>
          <param name="odom_frame_id"               type="string" value="$(arg vo_frame_id)"/>
          <param name="ground_truth_frame_id"       type="string" value="$(arg ground_truth_frame_id)"/>
          <param name="ground_truth_base_frame_id"  type="string" value="$(arg ground_truth_base_frame_id)"/>
          <param name="wait_for_transform_duration" type="double" value="$(arg wait_for_transform)"/>
          <param name="approx_sync"                 type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_sync)"/>
          <param name="config_path"                 type="string" value="$(arg cfg)"/>
          <param name="queue_size"                  type="int"    value="$(arg queue_size)"/>
          <param name="subscribe_rgbd"              type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_rgbd)"/>
          <param name="guess_frame_id"              type="string" value="$(arg odom_guess_frame_id)"/>
          <param name="guess_min_translation"       type="double" value="$(arg odom_guess_min_translation)"/>
          <param name="guess_min_rotation"          type="double" value="$(arg odom_guess_min_rotation)"/>
        </node>

        <!-- Stereo Odometry -->
        <node if="$(arg stereo)" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="stereo_odometry" name="stereo_odometry" output="$(arg output)" args="$(arg rtabmap_args) $(arg odom_args)" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
          <remap from="left/image_rect"        to="$(arg left_image_topic_relay)"/>
          <remap from="right/image_rect"       to="$(arg right_image_topic_relay)"/>
          <remap from="left/camera_info"       to="$(arg left_camera_info_topic)"/>
          <remap from="right/camera_info"      to="$(arg right_camera_info_topic)"/>
          <remap     if="$(arg rgbd_sync)" from="rgbd_image" to="$(arg rgbd_topic)"/>
          <remap unless="$(arg rgbd_sync)" from="rgbd_image" to="$(arg rgbd_topic)_relay"/>
          <remap from="odom"                   to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
          <remap from="imu"                    to="$(arg imu_topic)"/>
      
          <param name="frame_id"                    type="string" value="$(arg frame_id)"/>
          <param name="odom_frame_id"               type="string" value="$(arg vo_frame_id)"/>
          <param name="ground_truth_frame_id"       type="string" value="$(arg ground_truth_frame_id)"/>
          <param name="ground_truth_base_frame_id"  type="string" value="$(arg ground_truth_base_frame_id)"/>
          <param name="wait_for_transform_duration" type="double" value="$(arg wait_for_transform)"/>
          <param name="approx_sync"                 type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_sync)"/>
          <param name="config_path"                 type="string" value="$(arg cfg)"/>
          <param name="queue_size"                  type="int"    value="$(arg queue_size)"/>
          <param name="subscribe_rgbd"              type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_rgbd)"/>
          <param name="guess_frame_id"              type="string" value="$(arg odom_guess_frame_id)"/>
          <param name="guess_min_translation"       type="double" value="$(arg odom_guess_min_translation)"/>
          <param name="guess_min_rotation"          type="double" value="$(arg odom_guess_min_rotation)"/>
        </node>
      </group>
    </group>
    
    <!-- ICP Odometry -->
    <node if="$(arg icp_odometry)" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="icp_odometry" name="icp_odometry" output="$(arg output)" args="$(arg rtabmap_args) $(arg odom_args)" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
      <remap from="scan"                   to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
      <remap from="scan_cloud"             to="$(arg scan_cloud_topic)"/>
      <remap from="odom"                   to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
      
      <param name="frame_id"                    type="string" value="$(arg frame_id)"/>
      <param name="odom_frame_id"               type="string" value="$(arg vo_frame_id)"/>
      <param name="ground_truth_frame_id"       type="string" value="$(arg ground_truth_frame_id)"/>
      <param name="ground_truth_base_frame_id"  type="string" value="$(arg ground_truth_base_frame_id)"/>
      <param name="wait_for_transform_duration" type="double" value="$(arg wait_for_transform)"/>
      <param name="config_path"                 type="string" value="$(arg cfg)"/>
      <param name="queue_size"                  type="int"    value="$(arg queue_size)"/>
      <param name="guess_frame_id"              type="string" value="$(arg odom_guess_frame_id)"/>
      <param name="guess_min_translation"       type="double" value="$(arg odom_guess_min_translation)"/>
      <param name="guess_min_rotation"          type="double" value="$(arg odom_guess_min_rotation)"/>
    </node>
  
    <!-- Visual SLAM (robot side) -->
    <!-- args: "delete_db_on_start" and "udebug" -->
    <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="$(arg output)" args="$(arg rtabmap_args)" launch-prefix="">
      <param     if="$(arg stereo)" name="subscribe_depth"  type="bool" value="false"/>
      <param unless="$(arg stereo)" name="subscribe_depth"  type="bool" value="true"/>
      <param name="subscribe_rgbd"       type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_rgbd)"/>
      <param name="subscribe_stereo"     type="bool"   value="$(arg stereo)"/>
      <param name="subscribe_scan"       type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_scan)"/>
      <param name="subscribe_scan_cloud" type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_scan_cloud)"/>
      <param name="subscribe_user_data"  type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_user_data)"/>
      <param if="$(arg visual_odometry)" name="subscribe_odom_info" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <param if="$(arg icp_odometry)"    name="subscribe_odom_info" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <param name="frame_id"             type="string" value="$(arg frame_id)"/>
      <param name="map_frame_id"         type="string" value="$(arg map_frame_id)"/>
      <param name="odom_frame_id"        type="string" value="$(arg odom_frame_id)"/>
      <param name="ground_truth_frame_id"       type="string" value="$(arg ground_truth_frame_id)"/>
      <param name="ground_truth_base_frame_id"  type="string" value="$(arg ground_truth_base_frame_id)"/>
      <param name="odom_tf_angular_variance" type="double" value="$(arg odom_tf_angular_variance)"/>
      <param name="odom_tf_linear_variance"  type="double" value="$(arg odom_tf_linear_variance)"/>
      <param name="odom_sensor_sync"         type="bool"   value="$(arg odom_sensor_sync)"/>
      <param name="wait_for_transform_duration"  type="double"   value="$(arg wait_for_transform)"/>
      <param name="database_path"        type="string" value="$(arg database_path)"/>
      <param name="approx_sync"          type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_sync)"/>
      <param name="config_path"          type="string" value="$(arg cfg)"/>
      <param name="queue_size"           type="int" value="$(arg queue_size)"/>
      <param name="scan_normal_k"        type="int" value="$(arg scan_normal_k)"/>
      
      <remap from="rgb/image"       to="$(arg rgb_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="depth/image"     to="$(arg depth_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg camera_info_topic)"/>
      
      <remap     if="$(arg rgbd_sync)" from="rgbd_image" to="$(arg rgbd_topic)"/>
      <remap unless="$(arg rgbd_sync)" from="rgbd_image" to="$(arg rgbd_topic)_relay"/>
    
      <remap from="left/image_rect"        to="$(arg left_image_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="right/image_rect"       to="$(arg right_image_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="left/camera_info"       to="$(arg left_camera_info_topic)"/>
      <remap from="right/camera_info"      to="$(arg right_camera_info_topic)"/>
      
      <remap from="scan"                   to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
      <remap from="scan_cloud"             to="$(arg scan_cloud_topic)"/>
      <remap from="user_data"              to="$(arg user_data_topic)"/>
      <remap from="user_data_async"        to="$(arg user_data_async_topic)"/>
      <remap from="odom"                   to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
      
      <!-- localization mode -->
      <param     if="$(arg localization)" name="Mem/IncrementalMemory" type="string" value="false"/>
      <param unless="$(arg localization)" name="Mem/IncrementalMemory" type="string" value="true"/>
      <param name="Mem/InitWMWithAllNodes" type="string" value="$(arg localization)"/>
    </node>
  
    <!-- Visualisation RTAB-Map -->
    <node if="$(arg rtabmapviz)" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmapviz" name="rtabmapviz" args="-d $(arg gui_cfg)" output="$(arg output)" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
      <param     if="$(arg stereo)" name="subscribe_depth"  type="bool" value="false"/>
      <param unless="$(arg stereo)" name="subscribe_depth"  type="bool" value="true"/>
      <param name="subscribe_rgbd"       type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_rgbd)"/>
      <param name="subscribe_stereo"     type="bool"   value="$(arg stereo)"/>
      <param name="subscribe_scan"       type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_scan)"/>
      <param name="subscribe_scan_cloud" type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_scan_cloud)"/>
      <param if="$(arg visual_odometry)" name="subscribe_odom_info" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <param if="$(arg icp_odometry)"    name="subscribe_odom_info" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <param name="frame_id"             type="string" value="$(arg frame_id)"/>
      <param name="odom_frame_id"        type="string" value="$(arg odom_frame_id)"/>
      <param name="wait_for_transform_duration" type="double"   value="$(arg wait_for_transform)"/>
      <param name="queue_size"           type="int"    value="$(arg queue_size)"/>
      <param name="approx_sync"          type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_sync)"/>
    
      <remap from="rgb/image"       to="$(arg rgb_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="depth/image"     to="$(arg depth_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg camera_info_topic)"/>
      
      <remap     if="$(arg rgbd_sync)" from="rgbd_image" to="$(arg rgbd_topic)"/>
      <remap unless="$(arg rgbd_sync)" from="rgbd_image" to="$(arg rgbd_topic)_relay"/>
      
      <remap from="left/image_rect"        to="$(arg left_image_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="right/image_rect"       to="$(arg right_image_topic_relay)"/>
      <remap from="left/camera_info"       to="$(arg left_camera_info_topic)"/>
      <remap from="right/camera_info"      to="$(arg right_camera_info_topic)"/>
      
      <remap from="scan"                   to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
      <remap from="scan_cloud"             to="$(arg scan_cloud_topic)"/>
      <remap from="odom"                   to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
    </node>
  
  </group>
  
  <!-- Visualization RVIZ -->
  <node if="$(arg rviz)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(arg rviz_cfg)"/>
  <node if="$(arg rviz)" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="points_xyzrgb" args="standalone rtabmap_ros/point_cloud_xyzrgb" output="$(arg output)">
    <remap if="$(arg stereo)" from="left/image"        to="$(arg left_image_topic_relay)"/>
    <remap if="$(arg stereo)" from="right/image"       to="$(arg right_image_topic_relay)"/>
    <remap if="$(arg stereo)" from="left/camera_info"  to="$(arg left_camera_info_topic)"/>
    <remap if="$(arg stereo)" from="right/camera_info" to="$(arg right_camera_info_topic)"/>
    <remap unless="$(arg subscribe_rgbd)" from="rgb/image"         to="$(arg rgb_topic_relay)"/>
    <remap unless="$(arg subscribe_rgbd)" from="depth/image"       to="$(arg depth_topic_relay)"/>
    <remap unless="$(arg subscribe_rgbd)" from="rgb/camera_info"   to="$(arg camera_info_topic)"/>
    <remap     if="$(arg rgbd_sync)" from="rgbd_image" to="$(arg rgbd_topic)"/>
    <remap unless="$(arg rgbd_sync)" from="rgbd_image" to="$(arg rgbd_topic)_relay"/>
    <remap from="cloud"             to="voxel_cloud" />

    <param name="decimation"  type="double" value="4"/>
    <param name="voxel_size"  type="double" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="approx_sync" type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_sync)"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

This is how my tf-tree is being published for some reason https://imgur.com/a/Wp4ZodK, and this is how I'm connecting my kinect with the base_link:

```
 rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0.1 0 0 0 1 base_link camera_rgb_optical_frame 100
```

Lastly, I'm calling

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch depth_registration:=true
```

To launch my rgbd node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299504/could-not-get-transform-from-odom-to-base_link/) by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2018-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you see camera_rgb_optical_frame doesn't represent your camera in your case, the correct name is "camera_link"

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2018-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1